# NSwag (Swagger) creates swagger file with case sensitivity causing inconsistent parameter names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, swagger, nswag

I have an asp.net core project which uses NSwag as its Swagger tooling.
The issue I am having is as follows:

1. I have a Dto class describing the *Collection* entity:

#

```
namespace SchedulerApi.Entities
{
    public class JobCollectionDtoV2
    {
        [Required]
        [FromRoute]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$")]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 24, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Collection { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [FromRoute]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$")]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 24, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Tenant { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. The following API is used to add *Collections*:

#

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("tenants/{tenant}/collections/{collection}")]
[SwaggerResponse(typeof(JobCollectionDtoV2))]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTask(JobCollectionDtoV2 collectionParams)
{
}
```

3. This is the Swagger file NSwag generates:

#

```
{
    "put": {
        "tags": [
            "JobCollectionsControllerV2"
        ],
        "operationId": "JobCollectionsControllerV2_CreateTask",
        "consumes": [
            "application/json-patch+json",
            "application/json",
            "text/json",
            "application/*+json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "type": "string",
                "name": "Collection",
                "in": "path",
                "required": true,
                "maxLength": 24,
                "minLength": 3,
                "pattern": "^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$",
                "x-nullable": true
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "name": "Tenant",
                "in": "path",
                "required": true,
                "maxLength": 24,
                "minLength": 3,
                "pattern": "^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$",
                "x-nullable": true
            },
            {
                "name": "CollectionDetails",
                "in": "body",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/JobCollectionDetails"
                },
                "x-nullable": false
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "x-nullable": true,
                "description": "",
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/JobCollectionDtoV2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically the issue I am having is caused due to the fact that the path declares two variables `tenant` and `collection` with lowercase, while the DTO class declares the corresponding properties with capital case `Tenant` and `Collection`.

I am hoping to find a way to decorate the DTO class properties with an attribute that will explicitly declare the name of the parameter, something like `[JsonProperty("collection")]` (this particular one does not affect the output Swagger).

Appreciate your help

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no..

Comment: I'm still running into this issue..